# Need stock images to use in products catelogue for eCommerce templates

Tags: magento, e-commerce, opencart, prestashop

I would like to build a few eCommerce templates but have not idea where i can find sample images to use as dummy Product Images. If i decide to deploy my templates to a live server, since im not a photographer how can i get high quality images of the products im selling without taking the pictures myself, any stock photo libraries for product catelogues? Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're trying to do exactly. Are you creating templates for a specific niche? I.e. like cell phones? Or do you want to make more generic templates that appeals to a broader audience.

one thing you have to be careful of is copyright. Far too many times you see people making templates and using any image they want. This is illegal (in America at least) as you don't own the copyrights to those images. People try to argue that you aren't selling the images, but the layout and that's simply not true. The appeal of a template is largely in part to the images used. When you purchase a template, it never comes out the same because you aren't using the same images. So you are using someone else's work to enhance your own and is the same thing as putting someone's image on product packaging, for example.

As to where you can find images...that's up to you and your needs. You can certainly go to stock sites like iStock and purchase some. They have some fair rates but many sites do have different terms for template designers. It may fall into their extended licenses terms and that makes them significantly more expensive because they like to assume you're going to be making millions of dollars with your templates, which is probably not true.

If you want product specific images, the best bet would be to go to the sites you want, for example, Samsung if doing electronics and send them a contact message asking them their terms for usage of their products. They may not give you license to use them in templates but you can try. I know for a fact many cell phone manufacturers have open usage for their images to retailers because you're buying and selling their products. In your case you aren't so it might not be the same.

In conclusion, after such a long post (apologies) your best bet is to take them yourself or purchase them from reputable sites if you can't get the permissions you need from the owners.

Comment: thanx, appreciate the long post actually, every word did count

Comment: You can always mark it as the answer if you feel so inclined. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's depend on your need, You can hire a professional for designing images as you requirement or you can search in goggle there are many free images that can you use in your dummy site.
Here is a link [https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&safe=active&client=firefox-a&hs=j6F&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=RhiVT8oticytB7ub7PYE&q=dummy%20product%20images%20magento&orq=dummy+product+images+++magento&biw=1366&bih=562&sei=JxmVT5WjAoLprAe0mfT9BA](https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&safe=active&client=firefox-a&hs=j6F&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=RhiVT8oticytB7ub7PYE&q=dummy%20product%20images%20magento&orq=dummy%20product%20images%20%20%20magento&biw=1366&bih=562&sei=JxmVT5WjAoLprAe0mfT9BA)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Search [Wiki Commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3aNewFiles&offset=20120424004646&limit=100) for usable images as they normally have a friendly copyright (that at least won't get you sued by a manufacturer or Getty, etc)

Take, for example, [this image](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aRandynotaloka.jpg), you can use it for t-shirts, buy a rapper, etc. Read the license; I'd do this if I were in your position.

On the right of the page is the link [information about re-using](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons%3aReusing_content_outside_Wikimedia), on which is posted:

> This page is intended for those who wish to reuse material (text
>   and/or graphics) from the Wikimedia projects — on their own website,
>   in print, or otherwise. It focuses on Commons as this is explicitly a
>   collection of reusable media. The Wikimedia Foundation owns almost
>   none of the content on Wikimedia sites — it is owned by the individual
>   creators. However, almost all may be freely reused without individual
>   permission according to the terms of the particular license under
>   which it was contributed to the project, but some licenses may require
>   that the original creator be attributed. You do not need to obtain a
>   specific statement of permission from the licensor (unless you wish to
>   use the work under different terms than the license stated).